# Unity: switch based on value type in Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I have been doing a lot of research, and I can't seem to find an answer that will work for me. I have a dictionary that holds the values of all of my global game variables/states (things like inventory item picked up, etc.), and it is setup up like `Dictionary<string, object>` because certain variables are bools, while others are strings, ints, etc.

My question is: While iterating through the dictionary, how do I differentiate between them to determine which is a bool, string, etc? I have tried something like:

```
foreach (string key in GlobalGameVars.globals.Keys.ToList())
{
      if (GlobalGameVars.globals[key].GetType() == typeof(bool))
            // Do something
}
```

Unfortunately, it tells me object type and bool type don't match. Which makes sense, but is there any way to use an object and then test its underlying type?

Or is there an even better way to go about this that would allow me to forgo the use of generic object type?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is `GlobalGameVars` stored? Unity's serialization engine doesn't always play nicely with mixed data types.

Comment: Right now I just have it as a public static dictionary. When I get around to saving, I was planning on iterating through it and serializing each value.

Answer (score 1):

That logic should work. For example, this runs fine in linqpad:

```
var foo = new List<object>();

foo.Add("123");
foo.Add(123);
foo.Add(false);

foreach (var thing in foo)
{
    if (thing.GetType() == typeof(bool))
    {
        "I found a bool".Dump();
    }
    else
    {
        "Not a bool".Dump();
    }
}
```

Run that and you'll get:

```
Not a bool
Not a bool
I found a bool
```

But to answer your question, you might be better off creating a `Dictionary<string, IGameValue>` where `IGameValue` is an interface you define. Each implementation of that interface (say `BooleanGameValue`) would have whatever arbitrary information it needs, but also always expose the information that you need in your game loop code.

Comment: Do you think that could have anything to do with it reading from a list as opposed to a dictionary? I am fairly new to C#, but dictionaries seems to be weird that way sometimes. When you use IGameValue, I assume you mean a custom (created by me) data type/class to hold the actual value and the data type?

Comment: Dictionary works fine as well. What's your exact error message? And yes, you'd create an interface IGameValue and then implement that interface in a class (ex: class GameString : IGameValue). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have had other projects I have been working on, but when I have time, I have been researching interfaces, since I didn't know anything about them. After doing research, one question I have is: In this scenario, why would you use an interface as opposed to an abstract class? Since both can be inherited, both would work, right? Is there a benefit to interfaces that I am unaware of?

Comment: So I did some testing, and I found that while 
`GlobalGameVars.globals[key].GetType() == typeof(bool)`
didn't work, this did work
`GlobalGameVars.globals[key] is bool`
Not sure why one would work and the other wouldn't, but maybe that will help someone. And the interface suggestion was excellent. It doesn't seem to be necessary for this situation since I was able to get it to work as above, but I could see how it could be very useful in more complex scenarios.

Comment: Abstract classes are used when you have some base functionality that should be shared, whereas an interface is a contract stating that the classes which implement it will provide that functionality. Interfaces also allow for multiple inheritance; abstract classes do not. Interfaces are useful when you start using dependency injection and unit testing as well. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442312/when-do-i-use-abstract-classes-versus-interfaces-with-regards-to-dependency-inje